# How to get rid of \n \r characters in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have the following csv file that I converted from a an excel file. But now when I read it as a csv file in pandas, I get \n and \r characters in records. How do I remove all of them and save the clean file as a csv file in the end.
Here is an example:
[image]

In case you need a row of data, here it is:

```
0   L   irinotecan  Aldosterone\r\n-regulated\r\nsodium\r\nreabsor...   path:04960_5    Excretory system    2.010000e-06    3667;4306;5290;5291\r\n;5295;5296;6446;850\r\n...   23533;3667;3845;4306\r\n;5170;5290;5291;5293\r...   0.040274
```

Comment: In python you can use ```str.replace``` function. ```x = "One\n\r Two"``` then ```x.replace("\n\r","") == "One Two"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
df['columns_name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' '))
```

Comment: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @Saad How about df['columns_name'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ')))

Comment: @saad it is because you might have null value, you can either drop or use df[`columnname`]fillna(' ') for filling Nan value with empty string

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
```

To this:

```
wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum).replace('\n\r', ''))
```

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'